# How to check value in input using getElementsByClassName , Like this?

Tags: javascript

How to check value in input using getElementsByClassName , Like this ?

When i load page, I want to alert

```
HAVE VALUE 3 INPUT 
NOT HAVE VALUE 2 INPUT
```

How can i do that ?

................................................................................................................................................

http://jsfiddle.net/3AaAx/37/

```
<input type="text" class="xxx" value="111"/>
<input type="text" class="xxx" value=""/>
<input type="text" class="xxx" value="222"/>
<input type="text" class="xxx" value=""/>
<input type="text" class="xxx" value="333"/>


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    // this function for use getElementsByClassName on IE 7 and 8 //

    if (!document.getElementsByClassName) {
      document.getElementsByClassName = function(search) {
        var d = document, elements, pattern, i, results = [];
        if (d.querySelectorAll) { // IE8
          return d.querySelectorAll("." + search);
        }
        if (d.evaluate) { // IE6, IE7
          pattern = ".//*[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' " + search + " ')]";
          elements = d.evaluate(pattern, d, null, 0, null);
          while ((i = elements.iterateNext())) {
            results.push(i);
          }
        } else {
          elements = d.getElementsByTagName("*");
          pattern = new RegExp("(^|\\s)" + search + "(\\s|$)");
          for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            if ( pattern.test(elements[i].className) ) {
              results.push(elements[i]);
            }
          }
        }
        return results;
      }
    }

    var xxx_var = document.getElementsByClassName('xxx');

    alert(xxx_var.length);
});
</script>
```

Comment: why is it tagged with jQuery?

Comment: So loop through and check the value and keep track of the count that has value and that does not.

Answer (score 1):

Add below code after var xxx_var = document.getElementsByClassName('xxx');

```
 var inputCount=0,nonInputCount=0;
for(var i=0;i<xxx_var.length;i++){
  if(xxx_var[i].value != ""){
      inputCount++;
}else{
     nonInputCount++;
     }
}
alert("Input Count " + inputCount + " , and non input count " +nonInputCount );
```

If you use jquery it will be very easier code.

Let me know if you didn't understand.

Thanks
Raviranjan